# Как сделать input с масками трех-четырех стран без сторонних библиотек?

Tags: javascript

Как сделать `input` для номера телефона с масками и флагами трех-четырех стран без сторонних библиотек, чтобы по умолчанию можно было поставить Россию?
Искал по всему интернету, но есть только вариант для простой маски без флагов.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Это разве не обычный select слева от input? C option - флагами вместо текста. Если уже нашли решение для одной маски, наверно можно применить похожее и для других?) Переключая их при событии onchange.

Comment: @OPTIMUSPRIME разве можно поместить изображение внутрь select?

Comment: @UModeL Упс. А option оказывается не работает с картинками, только текст... Нужен самописный, получается)

Comment: @OPTIMUSPRIME хорошо, буду искать способ, пока что не могу понять логику

Comment: @OPTIMUSPRIME: для данного случая, такой селект - это пара-тройка строк кода.